# Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/osm3s+xml

Tags: ios, afnetworking, openstreetmap

I'm trying to send request to OpenStreetMap api, and I'm still failing to do so. Please help me out what's incorrect.

My method:

```
NSString *url = @"http://api.openstreetmap.fr/xapi?node[name=London]";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/osm3s+xml"];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFXMLParserResponseSerializer new]];

[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSData *responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", responseObject);
    [self stopProgress];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    self.textView.text = error.description;
    [self stopProgress];
}];
```

Error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/osm3s+xml" UserInfo=0x1702e1e80 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17403d080> { URL: http://api.openstreetmap.fr/xapi?node%5Bname=London%5D } { status code: 200, headers { 
Connection = "Keep-Alive"; 
"Content-Encoding" = gzip; 
"Content-Length" = 7166; 
"Content-Type" = "application/osm3s+xml"; 
Date = "Sun, 25 Jan 2015 21:18:54 GMT"; 
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100"; 
Server = "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)"; 
Vary = "Accept-Encoding"; 
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.openstreetmap.fr/xapi?node%5Bname=London%5D, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 (... a lot of numbers ... )>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/osm3s+xml}
```

Comment: It seems like you have to tell your client somehow to accept `application/osm3s+xml` as content type, or to accept just everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/osm3s+xml"];
```

Very clearly creates the header that OpenStreetMap is rejecting. Don't set that header: set it to a [value like text/xml](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#General_information), which is documented as the right value.